# C++11 on Mac with Clang or GCC

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, g++, clang

I have Xcode 4.5.2 on Moutain Lion, and I have install the lastest "Command Line Tools" but when I tried to compile with `g++` or `clang++` (and the options `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`) I get an error.
With `g++`:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-stdlib=libc++"
```

With `clang++`:

```
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
```

It's in a Qt project.

So how can I used the C++11 on my Mac ?

Comment: you need this http://libcxx.llvm.org/ which is the c++ library for the llvm project that is called by the flag `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Thanks - that was what I needed with a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you found, g++ does not support those command line options.

It sounds like you're using Xcode.

For clang, you should look at the project settings, and make sure that the "Deployment Target" is set to 10.7 (or 10.8)

What the error message is telling you is that libc++ is not available for 10.6 and before.

Comment: g++ does support `-std=c++11`, but the ancient version shipped with Xcode doesn't support it

Comment: No, I'm using Qt Creator and I don't no how to change the "Deployment target", and I'am on Moutain Lion 10.8 so the libc++ should be available

Comment: Found it, it's working with Clang if I had the option : `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`

But now my program crashes when I executed it whereas it work on Linux

Comment: I found what it's crashes, there's no relation with this problem

Comment: where did you change that option in qtcreator?

Answer (score 3):

I installed gcc-4.7 on my Mac to make C++11 work. GCC in its current version is fairly good at supporting C++11, so this should be a fair choice.

The installation can be done by [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and is not that complicated (at least I was able to do it...)

To install Homebrew if you do not already have it:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Now run

```
brew doctor
```

and fix whatever problems come up (there is something written in the hombrew documentation for that). Finally, install current gcc:

```
brew install gcc
```

If everything goes well you should be able to access `g++-4.7`, which allows `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-std=c++0x` if `c++11` doesn't work. Support for the `-std=c++11` option is relatively new in GCC and you might not have a recent enough version.

I'd trust Marshall on the libc++ issue.

Comment: The GCC shipped in XCode is very old and there are no updates for it. Apple is now using Clang and dropping GCC due to licensing issues.

Comment: Ah, well, that would explain the issue with GCC, then. I'm not that aware of what's going on with OSX, not being an user personally.

Comment: THat's doesn't work, the current version that I have is `gcc-4.2.1`

Comment: @Guillaume Ouch, -std=c++0x was added in gcc-4.3 IIRC.  In gcc-4.7 -std=c++11 was added as a synonym for -std=c++0x.  I think gcc-4.2 has hardly anything from C++11 anyway.  Maybe some tr1 library stuff like <array>, etc.

Comment: -1 for posting without having a single clue of the situation.