# Build Android NDK project with Cmake

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, makefile, cmake

I would like to generate my android native application with the android NDK and Cmake, so, I've downloaded the [android-cmake](https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/) toolchain.

Cmake generate my project successfully, but when I try to go in the generate directory and try to run "make", I've got the following error:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/ldz/Desktop/myProject
[  1%] Building CXX object Project/src/Main/Core/CMakeFiles/Core.dir/Main/Main.cpp.o
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'
```

I don't know what is wrong here, my project use C++11, here is my **g++ --version** result:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958197/c11-on-mac-with-clang-or-gcc?

Answer (score 18):

To build an Android NDK project with Cmake and create APK, you should do :

- Instead of using android-cmake, you should use the [fork from taka-no-me](https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake).
- Then use [Apk.cmake from pixellight](https://github.com/Uroc327Mirrors/pixellight/tree/master/cmake/Android). Copy also [AndroidManifest.xml.in, LoadLibraries.java.in, strings.xml.in] from this repo.
- Have a CMakeLists.txt like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
 
project(testBuilder)
 
include("Apk.cmake" REQUIRED)
 
include_directories(${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)
 
set(TEST_SRC
    ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c
    src/Main.cpp
)
 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x -ffor-scope -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -pipe -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffast-math -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wreorder -Wsign-promo -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wstrict-null-sentinel -Os -funroll-all-loops -fpeel-loops -ftree-vectorize")
set(LINKER_FLAGS "${LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--strip-all -Wl,-rpath-link=${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/ -L${ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/")
 
add_library(test SHARED ${TEST_SRC})
 
target_link_libraries(test log android)
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "ANDROID")
 
set(APP_SHARED_LIBRARIES ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH}/libtest.so)
 
android_create_apk(test "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/apk" "${APP_SHARED_LIBRARIES}" "" "Data")
```

This is Main.cpp

```
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define APPNAME "TestApp"

void android_main(struct android_app* state)
{
    app_dummy(); // Make sure glue isn't stripped

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, APPNAME, "HolyShit you did it !");

    ANativeActivity_finish(state->activity);
}
```

Comment: This answer is almost complete before gettin my upvote, how do I use the script from TakaNoMe? I see no tutorial for it. An example Cmake command line invocation? thanks

Comment: Instead of using the Android cmake fork use the android.toolchain file included with the NDK (which requires CMake 3.6)

Answer (score 6):

Based on Vi.:s answer I did a clone of android-cmake on github and added a modified Apk.cmake called android.apk.cmake. I use NativeActivity instead of pixellight:s LoadLibraries.java.

The clone is here:
https://github.com/Discordia/android-cmake

I created the example in Vi.:s answer:
https://github.com/Discordia/android-cmake-example

Comment: Please make a pull request to get this change into taka-no-me's repo.