# Porting a CPP application to Android

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, cmake

I need to port a `CPP` project to `Android` but I somehow got stuck because of the following things that I am not sure of:

1. Do I need to use some kind of java wrapper for my `CPP` project at all, i.e is it necessarily that I use `Android SDK` to integrate my application with `Android`? If there is another way, which one would that be?
2. I have seen some people claiming they have been able to manipulate their cmake file and some custom `android-cmake toolchain` to build their `“.so”` or eventually an `“.apk”` from their project. Would it be possible without a `java` wrapper to manipulate the `cmake` files of the cpp project to build your project? (source: [Build Android NDK project with Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207721/build-android-ndk-project-with-cmake))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, I would go with using the android java entry point, otherwise you will most likely bump into problems (you can make full native android apps , but I strongly advise against it).

One of the reasons is that you will want SDK function calls from inside your CPP, and using reflection on the java environment from CPP isn't trivial.

The steps would be the following :

1. Create a very simple C code that will server as bridge to your CPP code . Here are some sample C functions that I've commonly used :

   - OnApplicationStart
   - OnApplicationPaused
   - OnApplicationResumed
   - OnApplicationUpdate
   - OnTouchReceived
2. Export these functions and load them in your Java code (lookup JNI on how to do this)
3. Handle all Android-specific actions in Java, and all application specific actions in cpp

So the answer to your 1st question is that a java wrapper isn't mandatory, but it's HIGHLY recommended.

To answer your 2nd question :

Yes, you can use cmkae, ant, cygwin , allot of command tools that will end up creating your apk (It's up to you on how you feel comfortable).You will still use the android compiler since you are targeting arm.

The difference is that you need to change in your manifest.xml the entry point of the application from a normal activity to a native activity ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html ) .

As you can see, the difference isn't the build system, it's the way you define your entry point.

As a friendly advice, try using the minimal java wrapper approach. You might get to better results sooner, and it won't take you more then 1 week of research on the web on how to link java code to cpp.

EDIT :

As of demand, I will shortly explain how I would approach the process of porting a CPP application to Android :

1. Rethink your application to work as a shared library , using a C entry point :

a.Create a simple C application that will load yourCPPApp.dll (or .so if you are on linux)

b. In your .dll create the minimum necessary extern "C" functions to be exported in order for you to give the necessary information to your dll

For simplicity, we'll assume we have 3 methods :

```
 void StartApplication();
 bool OnApplicationUpdate();
 void OnScreenTouched(int x, int y);
```

c. Implement the simple C project that will make the calls to these methods externaly (so the .exe will call the methods from the .dll ! )

Sample code :

```
 #include "myCPPapp.h"
 int main(int arg, char** argv)
 {
      StartApplication();
      srand(time(NULL));
      while (OnApplicationUpdate())
      {
          // we assume we have a 480x640 resolution
          OnScreenTouched(rand()%480,rand()%640);
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

1. Now that we have things working in full native with a .exe and a .dll , time to make it work with a .apk and a .so

a. Rename the exposed methods from myCppApp into java compatible prototypes

```
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_nativebridge_OnApplicationStart(JNIEnv env, jobject thiz);
    JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_sample_nativebridge_OnApplcationUpdate(JNIEnv env, jobject thiz);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_sample_nativebridge_OnScreenTouched(JNIEnv env, jobject thiz, jint x, jint y);
}
```

b. create the java class nativebridge (case sensitive) in the package com.sample (you need t respect the names in order for correct linkage to native)

```
class nativebridge {
    public static native void OnApplicationStart();
    public static native boolean OnApplicationUpdate();
    public static native void OnScreenTouched(int x, int y);
}
```

c. add the load library statement in the native bridge in order to have your library loaded at runtime

```
class nativebridge {
  ....
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("myCppApp"); 
    // notice that the lib prefix and .so sufix aren't part of the name
  }
}
```

d. compile your CPP code with the armeabi compiler and create libmyCPPApp.so (ndk build system , or whatever you'd like... i would go with the ndk, it's quite easy , just go into the folder with Android.mk and call $ANDROID_NDK_BUILD_PATH/build )

At this point you will need to createa a .mk file that will compile your myCppApp code, but this is out of scope, you will need to do this research on your own (it's quite trivial once you get the hang of it).

c. use the native methods from the bridge inside your java app wherever you see fit.

A very good tip would be to go through a hello world sample of ndk :

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

Enjoy.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you've put in writing such a nice answer. I do however still encounter some issues, mainly because I'm new to `Android`.

So from my understanding, creating an `.apk` is what you want to achieve ultimately, i.e with the `.apk` you can deploy your project to an `Android` device. If this is correct, then based on your reply to my 2nd question, the only thing I'd have to do is to build my code with `cmake` and the `android-cmake-apk` and deploy this to `Android`. Do you think this is feasible?

Comment: The other concern regarding porting is that, as you mentioned, I'd have to use the `java wrapper` in the end. The way I've seen people using this is: 1. declare the methods that will be implemented natively in the `java` files; 2. compile these `java` files to obtain the `native functions signatures` in a `.h` file; 3. implement the `native functions` in `.CPP` file using the already-generated signatures. However, I don't think that I could do this since I work with a project that has already been written in `.CPP`. Is there any other way to integrate this `java wrapper`?

Comment: You don't compile java to get the native signatures.You need to follow a simple naming convention. For example, to have a java native function int com.samplepackage.nativebridge.dosomething(string smthing) , you will need to declare an Extern "C" fucntion with the following syntax "JNICALL jint JNIEXPORT Java_com_samplepackage_nativebridge_dosomething(JNIEnv env, jclass this, jstring smthing). Then, after you call System.loadLibrary(yourLib) the two functions will match, and you will be able to use them .

Comment: So you can go the other way around (which I personally find more comforting): create the extern "C" functions that you need for your c++ code to work, then create the necessary java class.

Comment: Regarding the code building, anything you build with is ok, as long as you compile the native with the correct compiler for the correct processor architecture (most common is armeabi-v7a and it comes with the ndk).

Comment: Thank you for your constant help, @MichaelCMS. If I don't bother you too much, would you be able to highlight the process of porting my `CPP` project to `Android`? Which are the steps I should follow? Just to make my mind clear of what I need to implement.

Comment: Ok, I've edite my post. This is my way of doing things since I'm more comfortable with CPP. I cannot break it down into simpler steps.

Comment: @magmablade FYI, it's possible to easily create Java wrappers using tools such as [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp).