# What's CMake doing with Ninja in Android 7 build system?

Tags: android, go, cmake, ninja

From the information I got, in the Android 7 build system :

- The Go provides a build support for the Soong.
- The Soong, instead of using make, loads the .bp/.mk files, and outputs .ninja files.
- The Ninja loads the .ninja files and builds the source code.

And I also found in the [help page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/release/3.6.html) that CMake includes a Ninja generator.

EDIT :

CMake is included in the [platform/prebuilts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/cmake/linux-x86/), but not included in the [Android 7 manifests](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/android-7.0.0_r6)

But I checked the android code again , there being so many CMakeLists.txt and CMake being called in some scripts under /external.

```
    ./external/clang/CMakeLists.txt:686:  get_cmake_property(variableNames VARIABLES)
    ./external/clang/CMakeLists.txt:711:    ${cmake_3_1_EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL}
    ./external/clang/CMakeLists.txt:725:    ${cmake_3_4_USES_TERMINAL_OPTIONS}
    ./external/clang/CMakeLists.txt:734:    ${cmake_3_4_USES_TERMINAL}
    ./external/clang/CMakeLists.txt:750:      ${cmake_3_4_USES_TERMINAL}
    ./external/clang/runtime/CMakeLists.txt:28:    set(cmake_3_4_USES_TERMINAL_OPTIONS
    ./external/clang/runtime/CMakeLists.txt:49:  get_cmake_property(variableNames VARIABLES)
    ./external/clang/runtime/CMakeLists.txt:78:    ${cmake_3_4_USES_TERMINAL_OPTIONS}
    ./external/dbus/cmake/cross-compile.sh
    ./external/compiler-rt/lib/tsan/check_cmake.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_android_mips.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_arm_gnueabi_softfp.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_carma.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_android_x86.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_android_arm.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_arm_gnueabi_hardfp.sh
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/scripts/cmake_android_service.sh
    ./external/opencv3/samples/android/hello-android/cmake_android.sh
```

Also, CMake exist under folder

```
    butter@server131:~/code/AOSP/N$ find ./ -name "cmake"
    ./prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/sysroot/usr/lib/cmake
    ./prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.15-4.8/sysroot/usr/lib32/cmake
    ./external/dbus/cmake
    ./external/llvm/cmake
    ./external/compiler-rt/cmake
    ./external/deqp/framework/delibs/cmake
    ./external/eigen/cmake
    ./external/eigen/bench/btl/cmake
    ./external/ceres-solver/cmake
    ./external/google-benchmark/cmake
    ./external/libcxx/cmake
    ./external/libcxxabi/cmake
    ./external/opencv3/platforms/ios/cmake
    ./external/opencv3/cmake
    ./external/clang/cmake
    ./external/google-breakpad/src/testing/gtest/cmake
    ./external/libunwind_llvm/cmake
    ./external/pcre/dist/cmake
```

So if the Soong could generate .ninja files , what is CMake's role in the Android 7 build system?   Just an alternative choice or just not fully replaced by the Soong yet?

Comment: Maybe there is no CMake? Just because CMake can produce ninja files and Andoid uses Ninja, too, does not mean CMake must be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Starting in 2.2, Android Studio on 64 bit OS, supports building C/C++
>   via CMake and ndk-build through stable gradle.
>
> In both cases, Gradle is configured to point at the external build
>   system.  It interrogates the external build system to determine a list
>   of all C/C++ sources that are being built in the project and uses this
>   list to populate the Studio project, enabling editing and debugging
>   inside Studio while still using the external build system to compile
>   and link the C/C++ sources.
>
> There is a set of maintained CMake NDK samples
>   [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-cmake).

ref: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds

See: [Build Android NDK project with Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207721/build-android-ndk-project-with-cmake)

Comment: The CMake is not as what I thought to be an Android platform builder , it just for App developers in the develop kit right? Thanks for your attention on this newbie's question!

Comment: @butter: Yes, You may build an Android NDK project with Cmake and create APK. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmake/info